# Is this a valid proof to show $\frac{n^5}{2^n}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Claim: $a_n = \frac{n^5}{2^n}$ diverges

Let M be arbitrary

Then 
$$
\forall \; n \ge \text{max} \big\{ \big[ \sqrt[3]{M} \, \big] + 1 , 3 \big\} \\
n > \sqrt[3]{M} \\
\implies n^3 > M
$$

And Since
$$
\forall \; n \ge 3 \\
n^2 > 2^n
$$

It is true that
$$
\frac{n^5}{2^n} > \frac{n^5}{n^2} = n^3 > M
$$

$ \therefore \; a_n $ diverges

Comment: $n^2 > 2^n$ is false for large $n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claim is false, and the part

> And Since
>   $$ \forall \; n \ge 3 \\ n^2 > 2^n $$

is erroneous.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should look at the graph of $y=x^5/2^x$ from $x=0$ to $30$ to get some visual understanding of this sequence:

[image]

so it converges to zero very quickly after a small bump of working out which of $x^5$ or $2^x$ dominates.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n = \frac{n^5}{2^n}$$
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)^5}{2^{n+1}}$$

Determine the converging radius

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^5}{2^{n+1}}.\frac{2^n}{n^5}$$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(\frac{n+1}{n})^5}{2}$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^5}{2}$$

for $n\ge7$
$$\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^5}{2} < 1$$

Or the radius of convergence < 1 for n >= 7

So the series converges

Answer (score 0):

Since both components of the fraction are going to infinity, you can apply [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).
Doing so a few times, you will get constant in numerator and $2^n$ in denominator, which is enough to conclude that the limit is equal to $0$.

The same is true for any integer power of $n$ in numerator, or in other words exponential function goes to infinity faster than power function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with computational mathematics, you'll know that exponential running time ($O(a^n)$, for $a>1$) has a much faster order of growth than polynomial time, $O(n^c)$, for $c>1$. And so your quotient must vanish to zero.